# kubernetes ssh connection to pod

Tags: kubernetes, ssh

I have an application where each user gets assigned a deployment with 1 pod and a service. Each pod is configured with a persistent volume, allowing user data to persist if the pod needs to be restarted.

Is it possible to allow the user to connect to their persistent volume via ssh? My application rests on this requirement

Comment: Can you take a look on my answer ? Was it helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Your application should be able to handle ssh connection. You have to install and run f.e. openssh-server inside your pod.
Please consider using sidecar concept to perform this task: in your scenario it could be ssh server running along with user/application. pod

**2.** You need to expose your application using service type f.e. Loadbalncer - take a look on [kubernetes services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types), then you will be able to access pod from outside the cluster using it and finally SSH to Pod and access PV (using openssh-server).
In your case you will have to use service type LoadBalancer exposed on port 22. Opening port 22 allows you to work with your application.

For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: your-lb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: your-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 22
      targetPort: 22
  type: LoadBalancer
```

After service creation execute following commands to verify your LoadbalancerIP:

```
$ kubectl get svc (#External-IP)
$ kubectl get svc your-lb-service -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'
```

Also take a look on such [issue](https://www.stackrox.com/post/2020/07/protecting-against-kubernetes-threats-chapter-2-execution/).
This approach should work but please keep in mind from security point of view it's antipattern.

Malicious code could be executed by gaining access to a running pod, starting a new pod, or exploiting an application vulnerability

This technique under Execution arises when an SSH server is running inside a container, which could allow an attacker who obtains credentials to that container through other means to gain remote access to the container to run malicious code and compromise resources.

**Best Practice for Mitigation**

In Kubernetes, administrators should limit service exposure and apply Kubernetes Network Policies to restrict network traffic and prevent unintended access to a container that is running an SSH server. Pod configurations should also be hardened to prevent SSH servers from being added at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Yes if you have ssh server installed in the pod (the container image). You can ssh into the container and access the pv mounted if any.